# QtQuick: Cannot access dynamically added property from children

Tags: dynamic, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I have a structure similar to this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Item {
        Component.onCompleted: console.log("foo ", parent.gridMap)
    }
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("bar ", gridMap)
}
```

This item will be created from another item via `createObject(baz, {"gridMap": gridMap})` where `gridMap: []`.

Why do I get an output similar to the following?

```
bar []
foo undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

For my part, if i try your code i get error 'gridMap is not defined'.

So just declare 'gridMap' in your component and it will be ok, QML isn't able to add new properties, just pass initial values to the one that exists...

```
import QtQuick 2.0;

Rectangle {
    width: 360;
    height: 360;


    Component.onCompleted: { // try your code
        var obj = component.createObject (baz, { "gridMap" : [ 3, 5, 9] });
    }

    Row {
        id: baz;

        // for newly created items
    }

    Component { // the component to instanciate
        id: component;

        Item {

            property var gridMap;

            Item {
                Component.onCompleted: console.log("foo ", parent.gridMap)
            }

            Component.onCompleted: console.log("bar ", gridMap)
        }
    }
}
```